# Stepping Thread Group throws error

Tags: jmeter

The Test looks like this:

"MAIN SCRIPT " -Test Plan
            Stepping Thread Group

```
     Test Fragment
                  Include Controller - TT3.jmx
                  Include Controller - TT6.jmx

         "TT3" Thread Group
                    Does  some actions like Login,Select Projoect,Logout
                    No.Of Users  : 7
                   CSV Dats Config  file : For UserName & Password(TT3.csv)


         "TT6 End" Thread Group
                  Does  some actions like Login,Select Projoect,Logout
                    No.Of Users  : 2
                   CSV Dats Config  file : For UserName & Password(TT6.csv)
```

When  I exectued the test Throws below error:

2015/04/03 12:40:11 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT3_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:11 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:40:11 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT6_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:11 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:40:12 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT3_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:12 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:40:12 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT6_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:12 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:41:33 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT3_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:41:33 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:41:33 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT6_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:41:33 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree

Could some one please advise me wher am I missing?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of including external JMX files is via [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)

As per [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) documentation:

> The include controller is designed to use an external jmx file. To use it, create a Test Fragment underneath the Test Plan and add any desired samplers, controllers etc. below it.

Looking into your log file TT.jmx scripts don't seem to have Test Fragments

References:

- [JMeter bug 55464](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55464)
- [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments)

Comment: Hi Dimity, You are right. What I did is I have recorded  two scripts by choosing TestPlan>ThreadGroup . I have created another script called Main script and added Stepping Thread Group and Added Test Fragment. Under TestFragment added two Include Controllers I.e one controller per script which is wrong according to you. Correct me If I am wrong,now I have to do the below

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Sorry I have posted before finished.Correct me If I am wrong,I have to do the below steps.                                     TT3- TestPlan                                                 ThreadGroup(2 users).                            TestFragment(under  I have to record all samplers,csv etc... By choosing TestPlan>TestFragment while recording).         -Save Test Plan.same thing i have to do for TT6(7 users) TestPlan and then create another TestPlan called MainScript in that SteppingThreadGroup,2IncludeControllers(1perscript) &execute script-Thanks a lot Dmitri for your help-Raj

Comment: Test Fragments need to be in "Included" scripts, not in the main one

Comment: Dmitri ,I have gone through the document you have mentioned as well as Apache JMeter document,I could not find abbot "include" scripts.Could you please tell me where exact I can find that in the Test Plan.And then how do I run 2 scripts together using Stepping Thread Group(9 users).I am a beginner and trying to learn the JMeter-Raj

Comment: Dmitri,could you please help me on                                                                                                                                                                                                 T1.jmx  "TestFragment"  T2.jmx  "TestFragment"  T.jmx  has  2 Include Controllers ie. T1.jmx & T2.jmx.   2015/04/06 07:33:41 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\T\T1.jmx  2015/04/06 07:33:41 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\T\T2.jmx