# Set variable in Included Controller not visible in thread group calling it

Tags: jmeter

I have the following setup

```
login.jmx
...
- Thread Group
  - Transaction Controller
    - Http Sampler
      -Regex extractor (sets variable test)

other.jmx
-Thread Group
  - Transaction Controller
    - Include Controller (login.jmx)
    - Http sampler
      - Header using the test variable
```

The problem is inside the other.jmx transaction controller variable test doesn't get set. If I copy the Login thread group into the other test plan it works fine.

How can I set variables when using include controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my situation I glanced over this line...

> The include controller is designed to use an external jmx file. To use it, create a Test Fragment underneath the Test Plan and add any desired samplers, controllers etc. below it.

Once I added everything under a Test Fragment in my test plan everything worked.

[Stepping Thread Group throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439455/stepping-thread-group-throws-error)

Comment: Please accept your own answer (to help other visitors searching for similar case, like me...)

Answer (score 2):

As per [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) documentation:

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So I don't think you can use a JMeter Variable defied in one Thread Group in another Thread Group as the scope of JMeter Variables is limited to current Thread only and hence it can be visible only for current virtual user in current thread group.

So if you need to pass a variable between Thread Groups you need to convert it into a JMeter Property first via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) like:

- to set a property: `${__setProperty(foo,bar,)}`
- to get a property: `${__P(foo,)}`

If you want the property to be a thread-specific, i.e. each virtual user has its own value, you can add __threadNum function as prefix or postfix:

- `${__setProperty(foo_${__threadNum},bar,)}`
- `${__P(foo_${__threadNum},)}`

  [image: JMeter Properties across Thread GRoups]

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

Comment: See my answer it is the real one, I never said I had a problem with the variable being thread based. The problem was unless you use a test fragment it doesn't work right.

Comment: As an added note: JMeter will ignore the thread group settings (but will read its contents) that is imported using Include Controller. So the parent JMX and the included JMX will be in one thread group. From JMeter manual: _For convenience, a Thread Group can also be added in the external JMX file for debugging purposes. ... The Thread Group will be ignored during the include process._